# webpack + mocha, how to tell apart the environment

Tags: mocha.js, webpack

I have this react + rails app that I use axios to communicate with the backend with, naturally I have to set up the CSRF token like this

```
export default axios.create({
  headers:{
    'X-CSRF-Token': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content')
  }
})
```

But this screws up with my mocha test as document.querySelector doesn't exist in that environment; Is there anyway that I can specify like when mocha is running this file, it will just export axios, anything else, it's that axios.create(...)?

Like so:

export default **TEST** ? axios : axios.create(...)

Here is the scripts section of the package.json

```
      "scripts": {
        "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha './app/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-core/register --require testSetup.js",
        "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
        "start": "node server.js"
      },
```

I am still new to mocha testing, and I don't have any mocha specific code in the webpack.config.js file.

Thanks a million!

Comment: Are you using karma with mocha or just running it directly? Does webpack process your mocha tests?

Comment: Hi bebraw, please see my edited quesiton

Comment: Can you try with https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-jsdom ?

Comment: I think what I want is to be able to just use axios instead of a preconfigured axios.create(...) in test environment, i.e., I actually don't want the document object

Comment: The npm_lifecycle_event environment variable is set to whichever stage of the cycle is being executed. So, you could have a single script used for different parts of the process which switches based on what's currently happening.